# What folder contains the Wallpapers for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, directory, desktop-background

Trying to find the folder that contains the Wallpapers for 14.04, I want to use some of them on my other computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're located in

```
/usr/share/backgrounds
```

Comment: Great thanks! I like my computers to have the same wallpapers. I know it a little wierd